# geneal term of Taylor series of the squared root of a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

Has it already been developed an expression for the general term of the Taylor series of the squared root or a polynomial of n degree?

Thus, if $P(x)=a_0x+a_1x+...+a_nx^{n}$

then $f(x)=\sqrt {a_0x+a_1x+...+a_nx^{n}}$

and $f(x)=b_0x+b_1x+...+b_nx^{n}+...$

where $b_n=b_n(a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1})$

Comment: So have you done the first few cases? What did you get? Might it be easier to deal first with the case $a_0=b_0=1$? etc etc